# Running the same unmodified query in SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I want to run a query on both Oracle and SQL Server. The problem I have is that the query inserts into a column called PERCENT which I believe is a keyword in SQL Server.

A straight insert like this fails on SQL Server

```
INSERT INTO testtable
  (PERCENT,VALUE) 
VALUES
  (50,'test');
```

To overcome the above SQL Server allows it if it is changed to one of the following

```
INSERT INTO testtable
  ([PERCENT],[VALUE]) 
VALUES
  (50,'test');

INSERT INTO testtable
  ("PERCENT","VALUE") 
VALUES
  (50,'test');
```

The problem now is that Oracle does not support any of the above formats. Oracle only allows this format:

```
INSERT INTO testtable
  (PERCENT,VALUE) 
VALUES
  (50,'test');
```

Is there a way I can run the above query in both Oracle and SQL Server without any problems?

Comment: Yes, "percent" is a SQL Server reserved word: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Oracle **does** support this format:

```
insert into testtable("PERCENT","VALUE") values(50,'test');
```

Here is a direct paste from my SQL Plus session:

```
SQL> create table testtable (percent number, value varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into testtable ("PERCENT", "VALUE") values (50, 'test');

1 row created.
```

Comment: Indeed; it's almost the other way around -- from what I remember, SQL Server will only allow double quotes for identifiers after a `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`. I don't know so much about Oracle, though. @ziggy What problems/errors are you actually getting when trying your example on Oracle?

Comment: looks like you're wrong - i've tried to execute this query in TOAD and native SQLPlus - the error occured (ORA-00904: : invalid identifier). may be there are some environment optioins must be set before?

Comment: It doesnt work. I have tried it already on Oracle 10G
> create table testtable(col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10));

Table created.

>insert into testtable("col1","col2") values('test','test');
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "col2": invalid identifier

Comment: @heximal: Double quotes make the reference case sensitive in Oracle; creating the table without double quotes on the column name make it lowercase by default.

Comment: Aha! This works insert into testtable("COL1","COL2") values('test','test'); 

Thanks heximal it looks like it is the issue with case sensitivity.

Comment: Ah, that would probably explain why everything in our Oracle database is in upper case. Well, you learn something every day...